# scipy odeint, solving ODE with a parameter that needs to change after state variable reaches a certrain threshold

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I want to solve a system of 4 ODE's, it all works however, I need 1 parameter in the system to change after a state variable reaches a certrain threshold value. 
[These are the equations to be solved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuDkN.png)  The parameter`KIIaAP` needs to be 0 before the state variable `IIa` reaches thethreshold, and change to 0.5 after the threshold is reached (`IIath`).

This was my code until now, only here I manually change `KIIaAP` outside the intregration and guessed when it should change to 0.5 instead of calculating `IIa` evefy time step and once the treshold is reachd it goes up to 0.5.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


plt.close("all")
IIath = 4e-8                 #Thrombin concentration threshold for plat. activation. (kg/kg)

PL = 0.0016                    #platelet concentration  (kg/kg == 200e9pl/L) ik dacht 1.9



def model(x,t,kIIaAP):

    IIa = x[0]
    II = x[1]
    AP = x[2]
    RP = x[3]


    kAPAP = 5.24e-2                 #platelet activation by activated platelets (s-1)
    kAPII = 0.73               #Thrombin generation by activated platelets (s-1)
    ksurf = 7.3e-6   
    kin0 = 1.7e-2                   #Inhibition of thrombin in interior cells
    kinadd = 3e-3                   #Enhanced inhibition of thrombin due to the presence of ATH III in boundary cells
   # kIIaAP = 0.0


    dIIadt = -(kin0+kinadd)*IIa+(ksurf+kAPII*AP)*II
    dIIdt = -(ksurf + kAPII*AP)*II
    dAPdt = kAPAP * AP * RP  + kIIaAP*RP
    dRPdt = -kAPAP*AP*RP - kIIaAP*RP



    return [dIIadt,dIIdt,dAPdt,dRPdt]


#initial conditions
y0 = [0,9.51e-5,0,0.0016]

tend = 2000
nsteps = 4000
dt = tend/nsteps
t = np.linspace(0,tend,nsteps)

IIa = np.zeros(nsteps)
II = np.zeros(nsteps)
AP = np.zeros(nsteps)
RP = np.zeros(nsteps)


kIIaAP = np.zeros(nsteps)
kIIaAP[200:] = 0.5
#solve model
for i in range(1,nsteps):
    tspan = [t[i-1],t[i]]   

    y = odeint(model,y0,t,args=(kIIaAP[i],))        #los systeem op voor 1 tijdstap
    y0 = y[1]                                       #oplossing van vorige tijdstap is nieuwe initial condition
    IIa[i] = y0[0]                                  #sla uitkomst van tijdstap op in array
    II[i] = y0[1]
    AP[i] = y0[2]
    RP[i] = y0[3]


def kgkg2molL(value):

    molmassIIa = 70e3 #molar mass IIa [Da]

    M = (value * 1000 / molmassIIa) / 1.06   #1.06 derived that denisty of blood is 1060
    nM = M*10**9
    return nM


#thrombin list in nM
IIanM = [kgkg2molL(i) for i in IIa]


# plot the results
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(t,IIanM)
plt.ylabel('[IIa] nM')
plt.axhline(y=IIath,color="r")


plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(t,II,'b--')
plt.ylabel('[II] kg/kg')

plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(t,AP)
plt.ylabel('[AP] kg/kg')

plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(t,RP)
plt.ylabel('[RP] kg/kg')

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
```

In short, 
I need help making sure `kIIaAP` jumps from 0 to 0.5 after state variable `IIa` hits a threshold value, automatically mid integration , and not manually like I did by defining the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `solve_ivp` and its `event` mechanism? I think the documentation for it has an example close to this question. You could of course also program similar based on `odeint`.

Comment: Your integration loop is faulty. You use `t` instead of `tspan`, which may not lead to errors in this case but greatly increases the computational effort.

Comment: I was able to do it by globally setting the parameter as 0, and the setting up an if statement in the loop using the solution of the last iteration.